# SCSS and CSS Organization in Asset Pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

So, I may be completely wrong here, but I am trying to organize my css files so that scss files are loaded up first, with some css files being loaded up later.

Here is my `application.scss`

```
// Core 
@import "core/reset.scss";
@import "core/constants.scss";
@import "core/mixins.scss";
@import "core/helpers.scss";

// Template
@import "template/main_navigation.scss";
@import "template/header.scss";
@import "template/footer.scss";
@import "template/template.scss";

// Components
@import "components/scorecard.scss";
@import "components/support.scss";
@import "components/event_report.scss";
@import "components/select2-small.scss";
@import "components/progress_bar.scss";
@import "components/carousel.scss";
@import "components/collapsible.scss";
@import "components/forms.scss";
@import "components/form_validations.scss";
@import "components/jquery_ui_customized.scss";
@import "components/screen.scss";

// Overrides
@import "components/jquery_ui_overrides.scss";
@import "components/chosen_overrides.scss";
@import "components/multiselect_override.scss";
@import "components/qtip_overrides.scss";

// Gem load
@import "font-awesome";
```

I also have a `vendor.css` file which has:

```
/*
*= require_tree ./vendor <- points to a subfolder with a bunch of css files
*/
```

In my application.html.erb I have:

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "vendor", media: "all" %>
```

However, when I view source in development, I see that application.css loads up fine, followed by all the assets in the `vendor` folder, followed by an **empty vendor.css manifest file**

```
<link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/vendor/chosen.min.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/vendor/colorPicker.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/vendor/confirm.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/vendor/demo_table.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/vendor/fancybox.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/vendor/forms.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/vendor/jquery-ui-numeric-min.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/vendor/jquery-ui-numeric.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/vendor/jquery-ui.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/vendor/jquery.checkboxtree.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/vendor/jquery.checkboxtree.min.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/vendor/jquery.chosen.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/vendor/jquery.multiselect.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/vendor/jquery.qtip.nightly.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/vendor/jquery.qtip.nightly.min.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/vendor/jquery_ui_overrides.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/vendor/scaffold.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/vendor/select2-small.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/vendor/select2-small.css.map?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/vendor/select2.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/vendor/select2.min.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/vendor/strength.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/vendor.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Why aren't these files loading in the `vendor.css` manifest file, and am I completely wrong in my approach here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the development environment Rails will load the individual files for you, for easier debugging.

To turn this off, set `config.assets.debug` to `false` in your development environment file i.e. `config/environments/development.rb` and restart your Rails app.

Comment: Setting to false showed me vendor.css correctly compiled as a manifest. Thanks

Comment: @Abram How do you mean? It's not normal to turn the asset debugging off in your development environment because it makes it harder to use Browser Dev Tools to debug CSS rules. Rails will compile your assets for you on staging and production by default.

Comment: Oh sorry, I just mean generally with the approach of having a dedicated scss manifest file followed by a css manifest file

Comment: @Abram That's an opinionated question - some will argue it's best to serve above-the-fold content through a `style` tag on each page but SPDY has made that irrelevant. Others will stay true to having only one `application.css` file on production. I can't definitively tell you what's acceptable here.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm assuming (hoping) there won't be a huge performance difference... as this method has simplified the process of loading my scss / css assets

Answer (score 1):

The reason you have an empty vendor.css file showing up is because you haven't put anything in it (other than the comment to include the files in the vendor folder). This is expected Rails behavior -- any .css or .scss file can contain both comments that direct the asset pipeline to include other files as well as CSS or SCSS code. If a file contains only directives then (in development mode) you'll see an empty file. In production this won't matter since you'll precompile all your assets and end up with a single .css file included in the HTML.